# Aligning the inline block elements from top

Tags: html, css

How do I make two (or more) floating divs appear like "big buttons" and let them float and be leveled? My problem is that the boxes are "partially leveled"... with one slightly lower than the other. I have tried to use `float: left` on the adminBox, but then they grow outside the container. Can anyone help me?

I have used this HTML code:
(http://jsfiddle.net/jf936/13/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="adminBox">
    <h2>Manage users</h2>
    <div class="adminBoxLargeContent" data-bind="text: usersCount"></div>
    <div class="adminBoxSmallContent">Registered users</div>
</div>

<div class="adminBox">
    <h2>Manage templates</h2>
    <div class="adminBoxLargeContent" data-bind="text: templateCount"></div>
</div>
```

and this style:

```
.container{
background-color: light-blue;
}
.adminBox{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.adminBox h2{
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;

}

.adminBoxLargeContent{
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;

}

.adminBox .adminBoxSmallContent{
    float: none;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle link for the code in issue?

Comment: Oh.. Never done that before..

Comment: Got to www.jsfiddle.net paste your code and ctrl + s Thats it - @thomas

Comment: done: http://jsfiddle.net/jf936/3/

Comment: @thomas Can you make the question title more constructive?

Comment: @thomas is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/jf936/14/

Comment: Sure @Mr.Alien. Have a suggestion?

Comment: @Mr.Alien That seems to be the solution. Thank's. How do I mark this as answer?

Comment: @thomas Posted, now you can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with <s>`float`</s>, the issue is that you are using `display: inline-block;` and hence the element are aligned to the baseline, inorder to fix this, you need to use `vertical-align: top;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/jf936/14/)

```
.adminBox{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top; /* Add this here */
}
```

Note: You don't have to use `float: none;` as nothing is floated here, so you can get rid of those unused properties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will be helpful for you:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf936/19/)

```
.container{
    background-color: light-blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.adminBox{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 7px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
}
.adminBox h2{
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.adminBoxLargeContent{
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
.adminBox .adminBoxSmallContent{
    text-align:center;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="adminBox">
        <h2>Manage users</h2>
        <div class="adminBoxLargeContent" data-bind="text: usersCount"></div>
        <div class="adminBoxSmallContent">Registered users</div>
    </div>

    <div class="adminBox">
        <h2>Manage templates</h2>
        <div class="adminBoxLargeContent" data-bind="text: templateCount"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had pasted an earlier (and different) version of the code. See on my jsFiddle

Comment: float: left makes it "grow outside" the container. Check http://jsfiddle.net/jf936/13/

Comment: I don't know what you talking about. What grow outside. In my answer I use float left and display block for your boxes and overflow hidden. Everything working normal. If you want use display inline block so do not use float. In your last fiddle you still use display inline block

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jf936/4/)**

**The CSS Code Change:**

```
.adminBox{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. It still "grow outside the container" (lack of a better word). It all goes inside a MVC5 app with header and bottom copyright stuff...

Comment: Thats a different issue. It has got nothing to do with this code. - @thomas